# How to add values in mySQL together with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite, mysqli

I need to add values in `MySQL` and see if its greater than another value then `echo` the amount of rows.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT created_at,seconds FROM table WHERE created_at + seconds > CURTIME()");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $num_rows;
```

Comment: Can we have the table schema?

Comment: Do not use deprcated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: Its my friends db im wanting to get access to but
created_at is a time such as 00:00:00 im guessing and seconds is a time such as 600 but I want it to add in secounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `seconds` is an integer column, use `DATE_ADD`:

```
SELECT created_at, seconds FROM table
WHERE DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL seconds SECOND) > CURTIME()
```

Comment: say the value in the row was car would it be 
(created_at, INTERVAL seconds Car)
or
(created_at, INTERVAL car SECOND)

Comment: The syntax is `INTERVAL amount UNIT`, where `UNIT` can be `SECOND`, `HOUR`, `DAY`, etc.

Comment: If the amount was last, wouldn't I have written `INTERVAL SECOND seconds`? Because the column name is `seconds`, not `second`.